# How can I disable popups in vs2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know how to disable these annoying popups in VS2022?  Is it even possible?
[image]

It is obviously very annoying and disruptive when they pop up every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Its more annoying that this particular internal error has been an issue for a long time with Visual Studio - though lately I haven't seen it.  I don't think there is a way to prevent these unfortunately.